# Function expression may be converted to lambda expression

Tags: javascript, typescript, resharper

If I have a snippet like this

```
module MyModule{
    export var myfunc = function() {
    }
}
```

then ReSharper suggest to convert to

```
module MyModule{
    export var myfunc = () => {
    }
}
```

however that's not working when the function is using `this`

```
module MyModule{
    export var myfunc = function(){
        var x = $(this);
    }
}
```

Why is the conversion not working when `this` is in use?

(If you wonder why I use `this` in a module, it's because this method is an event handler)

Comment: You mean resharper doesn't suggest to convert the function to an arrow function just because you are using `this`?

Comment: @MinusFour I read the question to mean that when the OP *does* do the conversion, it doesn't work when the function expects `this` to be bound as in a traditional function. (For example, the way you'd expect things to work when passing a function to `jQuery.each()`.)

Comment: @MinusFour I need to edit my answer. Just found out that it doesn't work when the function is inside a Module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arrow function is implicitly set up such that `this` is whatever it is in the scope in which the arrow function was instantiated. It's as if you wrote:

```
var myfunc = () => { ... } .bind(this);
```

I think the notion behind that is that it's often the case that such callbacks do want access to the `this` value from the outer context. As you're seeing, sometimes they don't.